Chrome Javascript and/or network stops running after closing RDP window (not logging out)
I have a Windows server whose only job is to run javascript which is injected into an open webpage in the Chrome browser. The javascript runs perfectly while the RDP session is open. The second I 'X' out of the RDP session, the application stops functioning (I can see it not doing the required actions on the webpage in a browser on my local PC). I re-login to RDP and the webpage is still open and functions as if it never stopped. It appears either Chrome goes to sleep, the network goes to sleep, javascript stops running--I'm not sure.
I already tried changes for RDP related to Group Policy and a Terminal Server registry key fix here: https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/keep-rdp-session-alive-0007.html#:~:text=Click%20on%20%E2%80%9CSet%20time%20limit,and%20then%20select%20%22Never%22. This didn't work.
To be clear, I am not logging out of the RDP session or the user account--just hitting the X. Everything is exactly where I left off when I RDP back in and functions normally again.
Overall, how can I keep the Chrome window and/or javascript and/or network alive after I close the RDP window?

Is the webpage running in a browser on this server? Is this server the web host? Are you sure this is the right way to do this thing? What is the overall purpose of the server, webpage, and injected code?

The webpage is not mine. It's a webpage that doesn't have an open API, but I need to automate some tasks on it multiple times an hour. I do it by injecting javascript into the page, waiting for messages (from my other server), and then doing actions directly on the DOM. It's really jenky, but I can't seem to validate through a HTTPClient and pass the proper tokens to backdoor through their API.
